# Index out of bound exception in Spinner OnItemSelected

Tags: android, list, spinner, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a spinner inside listview.

adapter for list

```
listQuantities = database.getItemQuantities(id);
Log.d("List size", listQuantities.size()); //getting 2 in first row
QuantityArrayAdapter adapter = new QuantityArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_item_black, listQuantities);
spQuantity.setAdapter(adapter);
spQuantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listQuantities = database.getItemQuantities(id);
                Log.d("size", listQuantities.size()); //getting only one in first row
                Quantity selectedQuantity = listQuantities.get(arg2); //index out of bound

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

adapter for spinner

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.spinner_quantity, parent, false);
    }
    Quantity quantity = quantities.get(position);

    TextView tvQuantity = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tvQuantity.setText(quantity.toString());

    return rowView;
}
```

The spinner has populated correctrly. But while selecting an item, it is showing index out of bound.

Comment: remove this **listQuantities = database.getItemQuantities(id);** in onItemSelected() and try..

Comment: It's because your mapping is wrong. You are passing position of listview item as id in database which cannot be always true. Your listview wouldn't be showing you `index out of bound` when you select listview item for first time, am I true?

Comment: @kalyanpvs same result when i remove `listQuantities = database.getItemQuantities(id);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK id is the item id which is used to get values from database. it working correctly when used to set textviews in listview row

Comment: @Apurva id is selected correctly from database
`List<String> ids
id = Integer.parseInt(values.get(position));`